# Cart discount on Virto Commerce Marketing Module

Tags: virtocommerce

I would like to do a promotion in Virto Commerce on the cart. In my example i would like to discount the cart with 200 SEK if the customer buys for at least 800 SEK, the VAT/GST in my example is 25%.

This is the effect I'm looking for:

```
Cart
subTotal:             640
subTotalWithTax:      800

discountAmount:       160
discountTotalWithTax: 200

total:                480
totalWithTax:         600
```

As far as i can tell the Marketing Module only supports promotions where the discount is applied before taxes. Se comment in storefront code:

[ShoppingCart.cs#L390](https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront/blob/6ffe03f3f5fb67729ba03879c41ff2c44665f96d/VirtoCommerce.Storefront.Model/Cart/ShoppingCart.cs#L390)

```
        foreach (var reward in cartRewards)
        {
            //When a discount is applied to the cart subtotal, the tax calculation has already been applied, and is reflected in the tax subtotal.
            //Therefore, a discount applying to the cart subtotal will occur after tax.
            //For instance, if the cart subtotal is $100, and $15 is the tax subtotal, a cart - wide discount of 10 % will yield a total of $105($100 subtotal – $10 discount + $15 tax on the original $100).
            if (reward.IsValid)
            {
                var discount = reward.ToDiscountModel(ExtendedPriceTotal);
                Discounts.Add(discount);
                DiscountAmount = discount.Amount;
            }
        }
```

I guess this is a common practice in some markets. But as this is for a B2C solution in Sweden. An advertised discount of 200 SEK on a 800 SEK cart should render a customer facing total price of 600 SEK including taxes.

[This is an img of my promotion in the Marketing Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05Xnl.png)

This gives me the following on the Cart JSON

```
Cart
subTotal:             640
subTotalWithTax:      800

discountAmount:       160
discountTotal:        160
discountTotalWithTax: 160

subTotalDiscount:     0
subTotalDiscountWithTax:0
discountTotalWithTax: 160

taxTotal:             160

total:                640
totalWithTax:         800  (Calculated. Not in standard JSON response)
```

So either I've miss configured the promotion or my implementation of the storefront code for promotions is lacking in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, VC implement only the one discount to the order subtotal policy:

> When a discount is applied to the cart subtotal, the tax calculation
>   has already been applied, and is reflected in the tax subtotal.
>   Therefore, a discount applying to the cart subtotal will occur after
>   tax. For instance, if the cart subtotal is $100, and $15 is the tax
>   subtotal, a cart-wide discount of 10% will yield a total of $105 ($100
>   subtotal – $10 discount + $15 tax on the original $100).

But we are working on change the totals calculation to make this process more flexible and extensible for supporting any calculation policies.

You can achieve what you want by a little customization within your extension module:

1. Extend `ShopingCart` class with following code

   `public class ShopingCart2: ShoppingCart
   {

       public decimal DiscountAmountWithTax
       {
           get
           {
               return DiscountAmount + DiscountAmount * TaxPercentRate;
           }
       }

       public override decimal TaxTotal
       {
           get
           {
               var result = base.TaxTotal;
               result -= DiscountAmountWithTax - DiscountAmount;
               return result;
           }
       }

       public override decimal DiscountTotalWithTax
       {
           get
           {
               var result = base.DiscountTotalWithTax;
               result += DiscountAmountWithTax - DiscountAmount;
               return result;
           }
       }
   }`
2. Extend domain `CustomerOrder` type with the same code as for `ShoppingCart` above
3. Register your `ShoopingCart2`  and `CustomerOrder2` in `AbstractTypeFactory`

`AbstractTypeFactory<ShoppingCart>.OverrideType<ShoppingCart, ShoppingCart2>();
    AbstractTypeFactory<CustomerOrder>.OverrideType<CustomerOrder, CustomerOrder2>();`

4. Update your storefront to latest version from dev (this commit required for normal work https://github.com/VirtoCommerce/vc-storefront/commit/2464548c171c811a9d63edba0bdf6af93e8c902b)
5. Modify `ShopingCart` class in your storefront - add same changes as you made in your new ShoppingCart2 type earlier.

Get the desired behavior
[image: Checkout]